# dynamic resizing of header + video + button to fit any screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, responsive

What I have initially done is a bunch of different media queries that target mobile, tablet...both in portrait & landscape to show exactly the header with video below and button below that. I am supposed to get all three of these variables (header, video, button) to fit no matter the screen size including desktop vertical. With the exception of the vertical desktop portion, this is working perfectly. Thing is, I have been asked to make it dynamic as opposed to using media queries.

So the aspect ratio needs to be maintained... having the max-height & max-width set to current desktop size. Then having the actual video height = viewport height - (header height) - (next button bar height). I know this will require some javascript/jquery and any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

I have id's set up for the following:

header id = pageHeader

video id = pageVideo

button id = pageButton

Comment: Are you using an HTML5 video player?

Comment: we're hosting our videos on wistia and using the foundation framework for the website. The video itself already dynamically resizes for mobile but it also needs to resize on desktop if only the vertical space is shortened (height of browser window). The header, video, & button all need to be visible at all times.

Comment: With HTML5 videos, it's pretty straightforward, see https://jsfiddle.net/3uo09wn2/4/

Wistia's player is proprietary, so I can't give you a straight up solution, because I don't have access to it

Comment: From what I see on their demo page though, they use a flash player, and resizing it would require javascript http://wistia.com/product/demos

Comment: looking at it again...without having to add extra code my page is already responsive and does same as in your example. Try making your screen size smaller up once you see it cut off part of the video continue to make the screen size smaller both vertically & horizontally.  As you see it will only respond to the width of the container but not really the height. That's also the issue I'm having.

Comment: Does the header and button need to stick to the video?

Comment: See https://jsfiddle.net/3uo09wn2/5/

Comment: No the header & button don't need to stick to the video. I have space between them. I can't seem to add an image here. I took a screenshot of the issue from your example. As soon as you change only the height of the window it start to cut off the button and video. Once it reason that state it needs to resize. Again this is without touching the width of the screen. Just try resize the bottom going up until you cut off part of the video. thanks for your help & sorry if I'm being super confusing!

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/3uo09wn2/7/ Sorry, can't get think of anything else from the top of my head

Comment: Thanks really appreciate it, although I guess it the header & button containers do need to be stuck to the video .